# Join elastic search results with an existing dataframe in R

Tags: r, elasticsearch, join

I have a dataframe of this form:

```
id <- c("1","2")
text <- c("text1","text2")
df <- data.frame(id,text)

  id text
   1 text1
   2 text2
```

I have to query an elastic db with the text variables, using the elastic package:

```
library(elastic)
query <- '{"query":{"nested":{"path":"aliases","score_mode":"avg","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"term":{"aliases.value":"%s"}}]}}}}}'

out = list()
for (i in seq_along(df$text)) {
  out[[i]] <- Search(index = "index1", 
                     body = sprintf(query, df$text[i]), 
                     asdf=TRUE)$hits$hits
}
```

As a result, I have for instance (after data reshaping):

```
result <- c("result1","result2")
es_response <- data.frame(text, result)

  text    result
  text1   res1
  text2   res2
```

In this very simple example I can make a join using the "text" variable:

```
full_join(df,es_response,by="text")
  id   text    result
  1    text1   res1
  2    text2   res2
```

But my problem is: **how can I make this join with the original ids without using the "text" key to make this join** (because of very nested data)?
I was wondering if there is somehow a way to pass (conserve) the "id" in the search query?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: If `Search` is a function in an existing package then you should include a `library` call that loads it.

Comment: What `id` are you referring to?

Comment: I indeed forgot to mention that I was using `elastic` package for search (I have just added it in the post).
@sckott: I am refering to the id column in the orginial df (ie the id of the text1 and text2)

Comment: are the ids in the df also the document ids in your Elasticsearch index?

Comment: @sckott: no, that's the problem. The ids in the df are from another source. The elasticsearch db is used to add labels to the df (from text variable) in order to make supervised learning.

Comment: okay, i'm not sure what the problem is then

Comment: Ok I try to be more clear: I want to add information to my initial df, linked to each text[i] observation. This information can be retrieved in the elasticsearch db by making a search query with the text[i] value. The problem is that the text[i] value in the elastic response is hard to use for the join because it is "merged" with many others text data into list of list which implies a heavy reshaping. So I would like to know if the elastic package allows to add like an index to the search query... But I think it's not possible. I'll try to add details in the post.

Comment: Maybe a simplest way to solve my problem: is there a way to have in the elastic response the text value used in the search query (in a dedicated column)?

Comment: I don't think that's possible - Each search is only 1 text string, correct?  if so, can't you just attach that to the output from `Search` as a named element or an attribute. You can email me here https://scottchamberlain.info/contact/ if you want to share more details (hard to help without seeing e.g., data)